Problem saving a tmap file: Receive error message - Unknown format. tm should be either a tmap output, or a list of tmap outputs
In RStudio, I cannot get the map created by the following tmap script to save to my working directory.  When running the script prior to the tmap_save line, I receive no errors.  However, when I run tmap_save, I receive the following error:
Error in tmap_save(st_map, filename = mapname) :
Unknown format. tm should be either a tmap output, or a list of tmap outputs
Here is my script with sample data:
# Load Packages
library(tidyverse)
library(readr)
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
library(forcats)
library(stringr)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggmap)
library(maps)
library(mapdata)
library(sf)
library(tmap)
library(spData)
library(ggspatial)
library(readxl)
library(haven)
library(RColorBrewer)
library(ggsci)
library(ggthemes)
library(vroom)
library(scales)

# Map Title
map_title <- 'Place Schedule Adherence Map'

# Initialize Map
tmap_mode("view")
st_map <- NULL

# Create timepd List
tp_list <- sa_sf %>%
  select(timepd) %>%
  arrange(timepd)

tp_list <- unique(tp_list$timepd) %>% sort()

# Loop Through Each Time Period
for (tp in tp_list) {

st_map <- st_map %>%

  tm_shape(sa_sf %>% filter(timepd == tp)) +
    tm_symbols(col='pgr_delay',
               size=.01,
               scale=10,
               palette = 'YlOrRd',
               group = paste(tp, 'Place Schedule Adherence'),
               interactive=TRUE,
               popup.vars=c('schedule_type',
                            'timepd',
                            'place',
                            'stopid',
                            'stopname',
                            'route_list',
                            'pc_late'))  
 } 

# Add Map Title and Scale Bar
st_map <- st_map %>%
  tm_layout(title = map_title,
            title.size = 10,
            title.fontface = 'bold') 

# Create Map html File
mapname = 'Schedule Adherence Map.html'

# Create Map html File
tmap_save(st_map, filename = mapname)

mtcars <- structure(list(schedule_type = c("WKD", "WKD", "WKD", "WKD",
"WKD", "WKD", "WKD", "WKD", "WKD", "WKD", "WKD", "WKD"), timepd = c("03:00-07:00",
"03:00-07:00", "07:00-09:00", "07:00-09:00", "09:00-14:30", "09:00-14:30",
"14:30-18:00", "14:30-18:00", "18:00-22:00", "18:00-22:00", "22:00-30:00",
"22:00-30:00"), place = c("AEEN", "AEEN", "AEEN", "AEEN", "AEEN",
"AEEN", "AEEN", "AEEN", "AEEN", "AEEN", "AEEN", "AEEN"), stopid = c(2108,
4138, 2108, 4138, 2108, 4138, 2108, 4138, 2108, 4138, 2108, 4138
), stopname = c("Elgin / Avenue", "Elgin / Avenue", "Elgin / Avenue",
"Elgin / Avenue", "Elgin / Avenue", "Elgin / Avenue", "Elgin / Avenue",
"Elgin / Avenue", "Elgin / Avenue", "Elgin / Avenue", "Elgin / Avenue",
"Elgin / Avenue"), route_list = c("58", "58", "58", "58", "58",
"58", "58", "58", "58", "58", "58", "58"), pc_late = c(11, 1,
19, 5, 12, 15, 21, 39, 11, 14, 6, 3), geometry = structure(list(
structure(c(-80.306392, 43.378458), class = c("XY", "POINT",
"sfg")), structure(c(-80.306576, 43.379437), class = c("XY",
"POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(-80.306392, 43.378458), class = c("XY",
"POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(-80.306576, 43.379437), class = c("XY",
"POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(-80.306392, 43.378458), class = c("XY",
"POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(-80.306576, 43.379437), class = c("XY",
"POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(-80.306392, 43.378458), class = c("XY",
"POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(-80.306576, 43.379437), class = c("XY",
"POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(-80.306392, 43.378458), class = c("XY",
"POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(-80.306576, 43.379437), class = c("XY",
"POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(-80.306392, 43.378458), class = c("XY",
"POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(-80.306576, 43.379437), class = c("XY",
"POINT", "sfg"))), class = c("sfc_POINT", "sfc"), precision = 0, bbox = structure(c(xmin = -80.306576,
ymin = 43.378458, xmax = -80.306392, ymax = 43.379437), class = "bbox"), crs = structure(list(
input = "EPSG:4326", wkt = "GEOGCRS["WGS 84",\n    ENSEMBLE["World Geodetic System 1984 ensemble",\n        MEMBER["World Geodetic System 1984 (Transit)"],\n        MEMBER["World Geodetic System 1984 (G730)"],\n        MEMBER["World Geodetic System 1984 (G873)"],\n        MEMBER["World Geodetic System 1984 (G1150)"],\n        MEMBER["World Geodetic System 1984 (G1674)"],\n        MEMBER["World Geodetic System 1984 (G1762)"],\n        MEMBER["World Geodetic System 1984 (G2139)"],\n        ELLIPSOID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,\n            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]],\n        ENSEMBLEACCURACY[2.0]],\n    PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,\n        ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],\n    CS[ellipsoidal,2],\n        AXIS["geodetic latitude (Lat)",north,\n            ORDER[1],\n            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],\n        AXIS["geodetic longitude (Lon)",east,\n            ORDER[2],\n            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],\n    USAGE[\n        SCOPE["Horizontal component of 3D system."],\n        AREA["World."],\n        BBOX[-90,-180,90,180]],\n    ID["EPSG",4326]]"), class = "crs"), n_empty = 0L)), row.names = c(NA,
-12L), sf_column = "geometry", agr = structure(c(schedule_type = NA_integer_,
timepd = NA_integer_, place = NA_integer_, stopid = NA_integer_,
stopname = NA_integer_, route_list = NA_integer_, pc_late = NA_integer_
), levels = c("constant", "aggregate", "identity"), class = "factor"), class = c("sf",
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

Looks like you are trying to save a static map as a HTML document, which is why you are getting the format error. Change the tmap mode from plot to view and then save as HTML.

I tried changing mode to "view", but I still got the same error message.

You will need to share your data so that others can run your code

To share data, can I just add the Excel file?

Yes, you can do that

New user here . . . do I just drag the Excel file to the comment box . . . or somewhere else?

Sample data has been added.  Script portion prior to tmap procedure also has been added.

You should add a link to the Excel file, not by pasting it in your question

Well, after a fair bit of searching on exactly how to upload sample data to StackOverflow, all I could find was to convert it to Markdown format and to add it to my question . . . so that's what I did.  I haven't been able to find any instructions on how to upload an excel file directly without violating security issues at my end.  Is it not possible for you to take the sample Markdown data above and work with it?

To share data on SO, you need to use dput(). First, run dput(st_places) or whatever file name you are using. Next, add the result in a codeblock in your question. The result will look something like structure(list(...). This link has some really useful guidance regarding how to create an MRE, and how to share example data in particular. Thanks

st_map <= st_map %>% looks horribly wrong (<= should be <-) but should generate an error assuming the loop actually happens... Did you type this in wrong?

Thanks, Tyrone, for the assistance on that . . . very helpful.

I did catch the <= typo, thanks . . . script still didn't work when that was corrected.

Simplified script with data (using dput()) has been added.

I don't think it's just saving. If this is the actual code, you shouldn't be able to see any rendered tmap ouput as there are 2 occasions where pipe (%>%) is used where + is expected.
# in loop
st_map <- st_map %>%
  tm_shape(...) 

# /../

# post-loop
st_map <- st_map %>%
  tm_layout(...) 

Try changing those to st_map + tm_... and you should end up with a valid tmap object

That worked, thank you very much!  Quite a straight-forward fix, grateful to you for pointing it out.
